# Model called "Order" does not work with CakePHP 2.x

Tags: cakephp, model

I wrote an online shop with cakephp 1.3 and upgraded now to cakephp 2.5. I used to have a model called "Order" that simply is an order of a customer with a certain amount and assigned products. This used to work till the latest upgrade.

I simplified / narrowed down my problem to this setup:

A table "orders" is mapped to the AppModel "Order"

```
<?php
class Order extends AppModel{
}
```

.. and a table "addresses" is mapped to the AppModel "Address"

```
<?php
class Address extends AppModel{
}
```

In my controller i just look for all 'order' and 'address' objects. This works BUT the key of the array for the 'order' objects is lowercase and this is a huge problem. As soon as i delete the model class "Order" it does work again.

```
<?php

class OrdersController extends AppController{

  var $uses = array('Address', 'Order');

  function index(){
      print_r($this->Address->find('all', array('limit' => 1)));
      print_r($this->Order->find('all', array('limit' => 1)));
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Address] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => my address
                )

        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [order] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => first order
                )

        )

)
```

Does somebody know this issue and can help me? I don't want to rename all objects in my code.

thank you very very much

Comment: Please explain why the key being lowercase is a problem.

Comment: ok it is not a "huge" problem but this means i need to edit all my code. and i would like to know why cake does this.

Comment: btw: As soon as i delete the model class "Order" it does work again.

Comment: Works fine for me with 2.5.1. Give it a try with a fresh app to check whether it's a general problem in your environment.

Comment: that is very interesting. you have the "Order" AppModel? maybe it has something to do with the encoding of the database. i was playing with it. can you post the sql dump? that would be great. i already tried it with several different versions. only the db in the background is the same.

Comment: Yes, I've used your example code. What SQL dump are you referring to to? The generated query? That would be `SELECT Order.id, Order.name FROM test.orders AS Order WHERE 1 = 1 LIMIT 1`, or the table structure? That would be `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS orders (id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, name varchar(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3;` ps, use @username in your comments to make sure the one you are "talking" to get's notified (I just saw your comment by chance).

Comment: On the bottom of the page you have SQL generated by cakephp in Debug mode. Please paste it in here. If you dont have it there check default page layout and make it appear. I bet its something with your database configuration/naming in cakephp or some other minor issue.